# Get list of all JS files loaded on a web page

Tags: javascript

A bit of a newbie question but what is the best way to get a list with full name path of all JS files loaded on my website?

To clarify: I have a page www.mypage.com - I want to get a list of all the JS files with their full name paths which are loaded on this page.

Comment: For the current page or all the pages? Current page, open up the dev tools look at network tab, filter for scripts. Or querySelectorAll and loop over the collection. If entire site, that means writing a spider.

Comment: current page... i did that but there wasn't an easy way to copy all the data simultaneously

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance):

```js
var entries = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
entries.map(function(entry) {
  if (entry.initiatorType === 'script') {
    console.log('JS file:', entry.name);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get all the script tags first::

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

And then loop through it:

```
for(var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){
scripts[i].src;
}
```

Comment: Barely helpful and definitely incomplete. What about XHR?

Comment: @Amit : better solution?

Comment: @Jonasw - Question is poorly defined IMO, no good answer exist.

Comment: Question is pretty straight-forward. I have a page http://www.mypage.com - I want to get a list of all the JS files which are loaded on this page.

Comment: @Amit : yes but ruhul tried to answer it and i think he did a good job. No need to critisise him. If you think his answer is incomplete add your own

Comment: could you please tell me where to place this code to test it ?

Comment: @Joanna Mikalai : between <script> and </script> on the page, or in the browsers console

Comment: @Jonasw - ruhul's first version (which was the version I commented on) was just the first sentence and first code snippet which was useless. Personally I find the current version to be of low quality, but it's not as bad (for example, a working snippet would be much more useful then sparse fragments).

Comment: In Chrome: I went to Console > Sources > Snippets. Created a new script and put your code. Run your code and also tried to evaluate your code in console. Got nothing.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai, run this in Chrome's console: `Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('script')).filter(s => s.src).map(s => s.src)`. It works for simple cases but there are possibilities to hide a script from this list, see my answer for more details on this.

Answer (score 3):

Something like that will do in modern browsers with ECMAScript 6 support. However, some scripts may remove their appropriate tags which would hide them from that list.

```
var jsFilePaths = Array.prototype.slice
    .apply(document.querySelectorAll('script'))
    .filter(s => s.src)
    .map(s => s.src);
```

Use normal `for` cycle if lambdas are not an option.

Scripts which were loaded through some data-loading method like XHR or JSONP and then executed through `eval` or `new Function` would not show up as well.

If you need to intercept and record XHRs and you don't have a centralized place where all XHRs are done, you will probably need to override `XMLHttpRequest` and add some logic to its `readystatechange` event to check whether the retrieved response is an executable JavaScript, see this question for more information: [How to easily listen for xhr requests with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093351/how-to-easily-listen-for-xhr-requests-with-javascript).

If you need to intercept all cases when a `<script>` is being added to the DOM or having its `src` attribute manipulated, you can use `DOM MutationObserver`, see [an MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for more information.

You may also need to intercept `document.write` and see if some script adds more inline scripts. Furthermore, non-script elements like `<img/>` may run scripts as well, as in the well-known XSS hack `<img src="http://nonexistent.url/x.png" onerror="alert('xss!')" />`.

Additionally, it is important to note that any such XHR-intercepting and especially usage of DOM Mutation Events and DOM MutationObserver are detrimental to the page's performance, sometimes rather noticeably.

Comment: Sooo, impossible, right? That makes this answer quite pointless don't you think? Just post a comment.

Comment: @Amit. Dear Sir, please excuse my humble efforts to help the OP. No, it is unlikely to be impossible, it is just rather hard to do. I added information to my post. However, to my best knowledge, answers on the StackOverflow are supposed to be ways to go, which is not always a complete code solution.

Comment: That's a much better answer. Personally I still think the most important thing to highlight is the fact that there is no guaranteed method to achieve this, but you did cover the most important parts.

Comment: Sorry, but I run this code in the console and i got an Array[0].

Comment: 1) If you run in console. remove variable declaration `var jsFilePaths =`, start with `Array.prototype...`; 2) It works fine for me in Chrome, have you tried it on different websites? May be your website doesn't have scripts at all? 3) May be your website loads its scripts through some fancier ways discussed above. This would mean that it is quite harder to obtain the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("script");
var myarray = []
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
var nametext = x[i].textContent;
var cleantext = nametext.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
var cleanlink = x[i].src;
myarray.push([cleantext,cleanlink]);
};
function make_table() {
    var table = '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Links</th></thead><tbody>';
   for (var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td>'+ myarray[i][0] + '</td><td>'+myarray[i][1]+'</td></tr>';
    };
 
    var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(table); 
}
make_table()
```